# Error when csv data contains comma

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET VB.NET, CSV File upload and FileHelpers, ASP.NET control is File Upload

### **Code to read CSV File**

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
Dim engine As New FileHelperEngine(GetType([MyClass]))
    For Each entry As [MyClass] In engine.ReadStream(sr)
    Next
End Using
```

### **FileHelpers**

```
<DelimitedRecord(",")> _
<IgnoreFirst(1)> _
<IgnoreEmptyLines> _
Class [MyClass]
    <FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)> _
    Public Prop1 As String

    <FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)> _
    Public Prop2 As String
End Class
```

### **Question**

There is some comma in data and due to that It is crashing.

[image]

Comment: What does the CSV look like?  You say there is comma in the data, is that contained in quotes?

Comment: Column value are like **Col1** value is `add,ress` and **Column2** value is `add,ess2`

Comment: Your tags show C# and VB.NET.... which language are you using. Please edit the tags.

Comment: You can give suggestion in any language either c# or vb.net. This depends on you. Totally your choice. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Add some sample csv lines to the question, some valid ones and some that cause the problem.

Comment: In what way is it crashing? Are you getting an error?

Comment: When there is some comma in column value, it assumes there is one more column

Comment: Usually this is taken care of during creating the csv, you replace all the commas in text of any field with any unique sequence of character.  FOr eg. , becomes %%. Later while uploading you replace it with comma. just after reading individual fields. There me be better solutions to it but this is what we used in a small application we had.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about problems with commas in data where the upload format is Comma Separated Value.  :head-to-desk:  If it were about how to insert code to change the commas in the data to something else, that'd be fine, but the way the question was asked shows a complete lack of understanding of the problem.

Comment: @virusrocks: I tried that still there is same issue.

Answer (score 2):

VB.net provides exactly what you are looking for in Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.  You can use it in C# however, as shown below:

```
TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(pFileName);
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;

while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                string current = parser.ReadFields();
            }
```

## Edit

Just noticed you are using VB - basic premise remains the same, but don't know enough about VB.net to rewrite it.  It will work though, as I had the exact same problem and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV looks like:

> value1,value2,valu,e3

it always will be 4 columns not 3
But if CSV looks like:

> value1,value2,"valu,e3"

I recomended use regexp split like:

```
var result = Regex.Split(csvline, ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
```

Comment: the values does not contain double quotes. problem is only with comma in data.

Comment: @abcdefghi So how would you tell if a comma is part of an item or used to separate items?

Comment: That's the problem here. I am not able to understand how can i differentiate it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,the file has errors and it's pretty much impossible to know what's wrong with an individual line except to say "there are too many fields when split by comma". There is no sane way your code can fix this error, you have to throw it back to the user who is uploading the broken file.

You can set the FileHelper's `ErrorMode` setting to `SaveAndContinue` (see [here](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.ErrorMode.html)) so that it doesn't throw on error, and after your loop check the `Errors` property and if it's not empty, report the problem to the user, listing out each `ErrorInfo` in the `Errors` collection.